# Android. Вылетает приложение на версии ниже Android 7.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня устройство на `Android 7.1`. Тестировал всё время на нём, всё работало и работает. При запуске на эмуляторе с `Android 7.1` тоже всё работает, но на версиях примерно `5.1 - 4.3` приложение вылетает (На версиях выше `5.1` не пробовал).

**Мой стактрейс.**

```
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter; interface 2636 'Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;'
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter;' failed
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'developer.chistov.messager.adapter.HistoryAdapter', referenced from method developer.chistov.messager.fragments.HistoryFragment.lambda$-developer_chistov_messager_fragments_HistoryFragment_lambda$7
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 3671 (Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter;) in Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/fragments/HistoryFragment;
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0011
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter; interface 2636 'Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;'
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter;' failed
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'developer.chistov.messager.adapter.HistoryAdapter', referenced from method developer.chistov.messager.fragments.HistoryFragment.onViewCreated
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3671 (Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter;) in Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/fragments/HistoryFragment;
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x002d
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter; interface 2636 'Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;'
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/adapter/HistoryAdapter;' failed
04-30 15:46:05.889 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x7370 at 0x5d in Ldeveloper/chistov/messager/fragments/HistoryFragment;.onViewCreated
04-30 15:46:05.953 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 10% free 3733K/4104K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-30 15:46:05.957 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 3829K/4204K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
04-30 15:46:05.957 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.931MB for 1127532-byte allocation
04-30 15:46:05.961 3100-3109/developer.chistov.messager D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 4930K/5308K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-30 15:46:05.989 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-30 15:46:05.989 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d77b20)
04-30 15:46:05.993 3100-3100/developer.chistov.messager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: developer.chistov.messager, PID: 3100
                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: developer.chistov.messager.adapter.HistoryAdapter
                                                                              at developer.chistov.messager.fragments.HistoryFragment.onViewCreated(HistoryFragment.java:64)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "developer.chistov.messager"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    })
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0'
}
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что версии суппорт либ у вас отличаются... в одном месте 25.1.1, в другом 25.3.1 - не нравится мне это...

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в `InstantRun` - поробуйте его отключить в студии. Ну и `build-clean` сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `developer.chistov.messager.adapter.HistoryAdapter` реализует интерфейс `android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter`, доступный с api23.
Используйте аналог из суппорт `android.support.v7.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это было так очевидно, ведь IDE показывала это, но я не обратил внимание, и даже представить не мог, что всё из-за этого.